# What data structure to use with 3d string array

Tags: java, mysql, list, data-structures, file-io

I'm working on a program that reads in a file and then outputs the data to a database.

The format of the table will be as follows:

```
studentID varchar(20)  
questionID int  
answer1 varchar(45)  
answer2 varchar(45)  
answer3 varchar(45)  
answer4 varchar(45)
```

The file structure will look like this:

```
studentID
answer1,answer2,answer3
answer1,answer2
answer1

studentID
answer1
answer1,answer2

studentID
answer1,answer2
answer1
answer1,answer2,answer3,answer4
```

Each line after the studenID is a collection of answers to a question. Each question can have up to 4 answers.

For example: 
The three colors in the Italian flag are _____, _____, and _____.

answer1 would equal green

answer2 would equal white

answer3 would equal red

I'm unsure how to store the data from the file. I first store the entire file in a StringBuilder array line by line. Then I count how many students there are. Then I loop through the data. Currently I'm able to store the studentID but unsure on the answers

Here is my code so far:

```
        //Variables
    int studentCount = 1;

    //Read in File
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File("hangman.txt"));
    int lineCount = 0;

    //Count Lines
    while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
        lineCount++;
    }
    StringBuilder quizFile[] = new StringBuilder[lineCount+1];
    int count = 0;

    //Read in File to StringBuilder Array
    while (fileInput.hasNext()) {
        quizFile[count++].append(fileInput.next());
    }
    fileInput.close();

    //Count Students
    for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
        if (quizFile[i].toString().equals(""))
         studentCount++;   

    //Count Questions per Student
    int questionCount[] = new int[studentCount]; 
    String studentId[] =  new String[studentCount];
    count = 0;

    //Retrieve Data
    for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++) {
        while (!quizFile[count].toString().equals("")) {
            //Read in StudentID
            if(questionCount[i] == 0) {
                studentId[i] = quizFile[count].toString();
            } else {
                //Read in Answers
            }
            count++;
            questionCount[i]++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you explain more about the file structure example? I feel that there's information left out about there being multiple question/answers in the file structure example and perhaps not enough knowledge about the questionID.

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: Each line after the studenID is an array of answers to a question. Each question can have multiple answers up to 4.

Comment: Yes. See normalisation